# perl6/rakudo: dereferencing-question

Tags: for-loop, pass-by-reference, raku, rakudo

```
#!perl6
use v6;

my $list = 'a' .. 'f';

sub my_function( $list ) {
    for ^$list.elems -> $e {
        $list[$e].say;
    }
}

my_function( $list );
```

First I tried this in perl5-style, but it didn't work:

```
for @$list -> $e {
    $e.say;
}
# Non-declarative sigil is missing its name at line ..., near "@$list -> "
```

How could I do this in perl6?

Comment: What exactly is it you want to do? The code in the first code block works fine on Rakudo HEAD at least.

Comment: The first block should be an explanation for what I want in the second block.

Comment: @sid_com's perl5-style `for @$list -> $e { $e.say; }` syntax is fine. Rakudo just hadn't implemented it at the time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't dereference variables like this in Perl 6. Just use `for $list`

But that proably won't do what you want to do. `'a'..'f'` doesn't construct a list in Perl 6, but rather a built-in data type called `Range`. You can check that with `say $list.WHAT`. To turn it into a list and iterate over each element, you'd use `for $list.list`

Answer (score 4):

These should work:

```
.say for @( $list );
.say for $list.list;
.say for $list.flat;
```

Since `$list`is a scalar, `for $list` will just iterate over a single item.

Answer (score 4):

Now, Rakudo 2015.02 works it ok.

You'd better use `@` as twigil of variable name as array.

Perl 6 is context sensitive language, so if you want array act as 'true array', you'd better give it a suitable name.

```
#!perl6
use v6;

my @list = 'a' .. 'f';

for @list -> $e { $e.say };
```